# Cannot get service account authorization to work on GCS script using Python client lib APIs

Tags: authorization, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

In attempting to write a python script to access GCS using service-based authorization, I have come up with the following. Note that 'key' is the contents of my p12 file.

I am attempting to just read the list of buckets on my account. I have successfully created one bucket using the web interface to GCS, and can see that with gsutil.

When I execute the code below I get a 403 error. At first I thought I was not authorized correctly, but I tried from this very useful web page (which uses web-based authorization), and it works correctly. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1beta1/storage.buckets.list?projectId=&_h=2&

When I look at the headers and query string and compare them to  the keaders and query of the website-generated request I see that there is no authorization header, and that there is no key= tag in the query string. I suppose I thought that the credential authorization would have taken care of this for me.

What am I doing wrong?

code:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      'xxx-my-long-email-from-the-console@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
      key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("storage", "v1beta1", http=http)

# Build the request

request = service.buckets().list(projectId="159910083329")

# Diagnostic

pprint.pprint(request.headers)
pprint.pprint(request.to_json())

# Do it!

response = request.execute()
```

When I try to execute I get the 403.

Comment: Are you on AppEngine? If not, have you tried using boto like the [docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary) suggest?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my formatting!  I took this approach because boto does not support service account authentication.  This is for a standalone service running locally on a device (a security camera), it is not an AppEngine use case. The camera uploads its media to GCS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working, however, the code I used is not fundamentally different from the snippet  you posted. Just in case you'd like to diff my version with yours, attached below is a complete copy of a Python program that worked for me. I initially got a 403, just like you, which was due to inheriting your project id :). After updating that value to use my project ID, I got a correct bucket listing. Two things to check:

1. Make sure the project id you are using is correct and has the "Google Cloud Storage JSON API" enabled on the Google Developer Console "Services" tab (it's a different service from the other Google Cloud Storage API).
2. Make sure you are loading the service accounts private key exactly as it came from the developer's console. I would recommend reading it into memory from the file you downloaded, as I've done here, rather than trying to copy it into a string literal in your code.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pprint
import oauth2client
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build

f = open('key.p12', 'r')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      'REDACTED',
      key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("storage", "v1beta1", http=http)

# Build the request

request = service.buckets().list(projectId="REDACTED")

# Diagnostic

pprint.pprint(request.headers)
pprint.pprint(request.to_json())

# Do it!

response = request.execute()
pprint.pprint(response)
```

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for the positive response. I initially thought that my lack of having the GCS JSON API enabled was the problem, but then I was able to get an OK and a bucket list from the web page I mentioned above. Maybe that page uses a different authentication scheme... I requested access to the JSON API yesterday and it has not yet been granted. I'll try again when I get that approval.

Comment: If by the web page you mean the Google Cloud Storage web UI, that uses the older XML API, not the new JSON API so that wouldn't necessarily verify your access via the JSON API. Given you requested access yesterday, I'm betting that was your problem. At any rate, comment here if you don't get access soon or get access and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Marc - The approval came through just now and it works as expected. I was thrown because the web-based api-explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1beta1/storage.buckets.list?projectId=) returns JSON, so I presumed it was using the JSON API.

Comment: Glad to hear it, David. Welcome!